# Feature detection and matching - Retinal images

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I want to automatically register two fundus (retinal) images together using OpenCV. I have done the registration in Matlab using control points that I selected manually from each image. This approach worked very well, and I obtained really good results with affine transformations and with non-linear approaches, such as second-order and cubic polynomial transformations.

A little more about my fundus images: the two images sometimes have very different contrasts, and are rotated and translated by large values. There's nothing I can do about the translation/rotation; that's the way the data sets are.

What I have tried so far in OpenCV is I tried the various feature detector and descriptors available to extract my keypoints and find the matches. However, since my images are of lower contrast, sometimes I do not obtain matches at all (this is pretty much always the case).

I wanted to know if there are particular ideas that I should work on if I have not done so before? Any helpful pointers/hints would also go a long way. Thanks!

These were the feature detectors I tried: `SIFT, SURF, MSER, ORB, and FAST`

These were the feature descriptors I tried: `FREAK, SURF, BRIEF, ORB, and FAST`

Examples of my output are shown below:

**EDIT:** Links to original images:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV1q6.jpg)  [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYnC2.jpg)

**EDIT:** This image shows the two input images, side-by-side. 
[image: out]

**EDIT:** This image shows the matches between the two images after applying the ORB feature detector, and the FREAK feature descriptor. The matches are bad. (obviously)
[image: out2]

Comment: Are the matches you show in the second image what you'd expect or a bad case?

Comment: The matches in the image that I have shown are those that I obtained after detecting ORB detector and the FREAK descriptor. I applied SIFT to the two images, but the matches were not very good.

Comment: So those matches in the image are good?

Comment: @Unapiedra No, they were worse: http://snag.gy/P0UO3.jpg

Comment: Let's be clear: I am talking about the second image you are showing in your question. Are you happy with those matches?

Comment: @Unapiedra No, I am not happy with those matches. The matches are nowhere close (obviously) to where I expect them to be.  I put those two images up to show SO readers that those were examples of my images. The image on the top is that of just the two images displayed side by side, and the image at the bottom is the matches obtained by applying the ORB detector and the FREAK descriptor.

Comment: Do you understand why you got bad matches? I might be wrong and don't take this the wrong way but it seems to me that you are just throwing a set of techniques at your problem and hoping that it would do the job without actually understanding why or why why they would not work. I think you have a better chance of solving this if you could motivate scientifically why one method is preferred over the others for your specific problem.

Comment: @kkuilla You're right. I just threw in a bunch of things because this is my first pass to see which combination of detector + descriptor gives me the best result. From my experiment, I realized that the ORB detector and descriptor is better than the others. Now, I need to understand why it is better than the others (scientifically) and why it does not work well (again, scientifically). SIFT should have worked, but didn't. I'm trying to see why, which is why I had asked the question "I wanted to know if there are particular ideas that I should work on if I have not done so before?" originally.

Comment: That's the right attitude... :-)

Comment: @kkuilla I think the descriptors that I obtain from my image are not descriptive enough. The brute-force matcher, therefore, is matching the wrong keypoints. I tried to pass the color image first, then the green channel alone, and finally, the grayscale image. None of the images worked. There are a number of false outliers which I did not expect in all of them. I thought SIFT (or, atleast SURF) would give me a reasonable set of good matches, but that is not the case.

Comment: Maybe you're better here by finding the dominant veins for a coarse registration and use block matching for fine adjustment. But can you post the original images without drawn matches? Maybe parameter tuning in SIFT/SURF will work here if you dont just find features at the border...

Comment: big problems are imho the big distortion (because of fisheye lens? and because of the roundness of the retina). maybe you can find some heuristic to undistort the images so that veins and structures are more identical in both images.

Comment: @Micka Images are uploaded.

Comment: This problem would probably be much simpler if you could reproject your image into spherical coordinates representing the retina. Then a simple cross-correlation of a highpass-filtered image could pick things out. I don't know how such feasible such reprojection is, given the optics of the fundus imager.

Comment: in Feature detection if keypoints are unique matching should be better. In your case unique keypoints are low. you may try to avoid to unwanted keypoints for perfect matching.

Comment: Try this one http://www.vision.cs.rpi.edu/gdbicp/exec/
It is described in good paper "Registration of challenging image pairs:
initialization, estimation, and decision"

Answer (score 0):

- You should definitely include SIFT in the descriptors. It's the go-to descriptor.
- With any of the detectors and descriptors you will have reasonably large numbers of outliers in matching. Therefore it is important to estimate any transformation in a robust way. Here, the solution that works well in most cases is RANSAC. There is a RANSAC implementation available in OpenCV.

## Update

Your images are quite different to normal (photographic) images.

Even for me it is difficult to say how the image pairs are transformed. When I do see it, I look at longer lines and their branches, not at small patches. So, I wouldn't expect a algorithm to do it.

---

I'd experiment with the parameters available in the detectors.

For SIFT those are described and can be found [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/sift.html) (Matlab vl_feat). Particularly, I'd look at `edge_threshold` and `peak_threshold`, and maybe oversample the image by using the `-1th octave`.

In OpenCV the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#sift-sift) provides the following parameters, all of which you want to change so as to get *more* detections.

- `nfeatures` – The number of best features to retain. The features are ranked by their scores (measured in SIFT algorithm as the local contrast)
- `OctaveLayers` – The number of layers in each octave. 3 is the value used in D. Lowe paper. The number of octaves is computed automatically from the image resolution.
- `contrastThreshold` – The contrast threshold used to filter out weak features in semi-uniform (low-contrast) regions. The larger the threshold, the less features are produced by the detector.
- `edgeThreshold` – The threshold used to filter out edge-like features. Note that the its meaning is different from the contrastThreshold, i.e. the larger the edgeThreshold, the less features are filtered out (more features are retained).
- `sigma` – The sigma of the Gaussian applied to the input image at the octave #0. If your image is captured with a weak camera with soft lenses, you might want to reduce the number.

### Another Thought

There is a paper by Efros' group where they describe a descriptor that might be suitable to your problem. The descriptor is geometric in nature. They take one interest point and then use the four closest neighbours around it to compute the descriptor. These four points form two triangles, the ratio of the areas of the triangles becomes the descriptor. I'll have to find the paper for details.

Comment: RANSAC is an algorithm to get rid of the outliers. I can clearly see that not one of the matches are right. So, even while warping the image with the `CV_RANSAC` command, the result was wrong.

Comment: I updated my answer. I understood your initial question differently but you were able to clarify this. In general the transformation is so strong that feature descriptors might not be invariant enough for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, you helped clarify a few things that I have been working on with the parameters in the OpenCV SIFT function. When I entered 2 as the number of OctaveLayers, it gave me a larger (but not necessarily better) number of matches than the number I obtained when I entered 5 for the same. Logically, the Gaussian filter covers a larger range of pixels at level 5 in the pyramid, so I expected a smaller number of features detected. My homography and warped image were way off with 2 octave layers. It looks like I may need to tune parameters to achieve a reasonable amount of matching.